# Apple iPod earphone problem

Tags: ipod-shuffle, ear-phones

My iPod shuffle Is just 7 months old and the earphones has a problem. The output sound is very low. I just now got my friends earphones and checked, the sound was loud and clear. What could be the problem. How can I rectify it?

Comment: I agree with the two answers (so far) but would suggest grabbing a new pair of non-apple headphones, your ears will thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like to me that your earphones have started to prematurely break down.  How does the cable look?  Is there bends or twists near the ends?  If there is then perhaps a wire is broken inside the cable.  Normally this would mean no sound rather than a decrease in volume.  Either way it seems that the earphones will need to be replaced completely.

Are you using the apple in ear earphones?  If so then simply replace the steel mesh inside the earphones by simply unscrewing them.  If you lost your extras you can find them on Amazon through a third party source.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with earphones. Unfortunately there is no way to fix them.

If your iPod is still under warranty (at 7 months, it is), and quite frequently even if it's not, if you take it back to an Apple Store and talk to an assistant they will simply give you a new pair for free.